# Creating a React CSS object with clamp and focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create an object to use it in inline style but I don't know how to how to write `clamp` and `after` the right way.

```
const PhoneInputStyle = {
    fontSize: clamp("13px", "1.111vw", "16px"),   /*this is giving me trouble
    lineHeight: clamp("15px", "1.319vw", "19px"), */
    position: "relative",
    width: "100%",
    height: "51px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: "8px 16px",
    border: "1px solid ${COLOR_NOT_BLACK}",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    outline: "none",
    &:focus {                                           /*this is giving me trouble
        border: "1px solid ${COLOR_SALMON} !important",
    }                                                   */
    gridRowStart: "1",
    gridColumnStart: "1"
}
```

The error I get on `clamp` is : `Cannot find name 'clamp'`

What I get on `focus` is : `Expression expected` (on the `&`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the whole thing a string e.g. `{fontSize: "clamp(13px, 1.111vw, 16px)"}`

For the focus, I think you'll need something like: https://styled-components.com/

-edit-

Perhaps you could create a wrapper component that you can set an onHover event handler on.

Something along the lines of...

```
<div
  style={isShown ? {border: "1px solid ${COLOR_SALMON}"}: ""}
  onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} 
  onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
>
  {children}
</div>
```

This would probably even work without needing to set a wrapper component.

Comment: Thanks, clamp works now ! Do you know how I should write focus for it to work too ?

Comment: I've updated my answer about that.

Comment: Sadly, I can't use styled components because I have to pass the css as inline style (I'm using a library that accepts custom style only through props).

Comment: Ah okay. Perhaps there's something else that will fit that pattern. Unfortunately it appears React inline styles on it's own doesn't support :focus.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will just remove the focus then, it ain't that important

Comment: In case you change your mind, I've updated my answer with another suggestion that might be more in keeping with your current design pattern.